# Running prolog on a mac

Tags: macos, installation, osx-mavericks, swi-prolog

I am having the hardest trouble trying to run SWI-prolog on my Mac.

When I type:

```
/opt/bin/local/swipl
```

I get an error saying:

```
/opt/local/bin/swipl: No such file or directory
```

When I just type "swipl" I get:

```
swipl: command not found
```

I've tried this on both terminal and XQuartz. I've even gone into

```
/Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/MacOS
```

to see if that would do anything, however the prolog "Welcome" text never appears. Quite possibly the closest I ever got it to work was when I typed "pl" when inside the MacOS folder. However I was left with my terminal doing nothing and had to use Crtl-D.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Did I install something incorrectly?

I'm running on a Mac OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks. I placed the SWI-Prolog application into my application folder and I also downloaded XQuartz per recommendation by the website.

Comment: what version of SWI are you working with?

Comment: Also, have you tried adding `/Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/MacOs` to your `PATH`? I believe this is what I have done, since the swipl executable is located therein.

Answer (score 90):

If you have [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) installed, you can simply run

```
brew install swi-prolog
```

from Terminal, which will build it from source in one command.

You can then run the interpreter using `swipl`.

Comment: Also, I first needed to `brew tap homebrew/x11`.

Comment: I've removed the 'brew tap' command because it's not necessary anymore, homebrew changed the location of the formula.

Comment: I get **Error: No available formula for swi-prolog**. Even after first running `brew tap homebrew/x11`

Comment: I want the older version of swi-prolog, what should I do?

Answer (score 14):

There are three sensible ways of installing SWI-Prolog on MacOS X, in increasing order of complexity:

1. Download the SWI-Prolog application. In this case, you just download a disk image, open it, and drag the application to your disk (e.g. to your `Applications` folder. You use the application as any other application by double-clicking on its icon. If you want to also use the binary inside the application bundle, add the `Contents/MacOS` directory inside it to your system path (for example, assuming that you copied the SWI-Prolog application to your applications folder, do `export PATH=/Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/MacOS:$PATH` in your shell configuration file).
2. Using MacPorts. Assuming it's installed and up-to-date, simply type either `sudo port install swi-prolog` for the stable version or `sudo port install swi-prolog-devel` for the development version. Replace `sudo port install` by `sudo port -u upgrade` when upgrading the installed version. It you're already using MacPorts, then `/opt/local/bin` should already be in your system path. Type `echo $PATH` in a `Terminal` window to check.
3. Compiling from sources. In this case, download the source archive, uncompress it, and follow the instructions in the `README.MacOSX` file.

Comment: I did the first option, and I get a window where I can put in prolog commands, with the familiar ?-. So that's good, but I'm having a hard time loading a pl file. Usually you can do [fileName]. but this doesn't work, I'm guessing because it doesn't know where to look for this file. Any idea how I fix that?

Comment: Call the predicate `pwd/0`to check the current directory. You can always change it by calling the `cd/1` predicate. Or give a relative or absolute file path when consulting a file.

Answer (score 6):

The OSX EI Captian has this command for swi-prolog installation

```
brew install homebrew/x11/swi-prolog
```

Comment: Because of some changes on homebrews side, this doesn't work anymore. See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Homebrew has moved swi-prolog to the top a few days ago and because of this, the other answers are not valid anymore. The reason for that: the swi-prolog formula was located in the x11 bottle but the x11 dependency is only optional.

As of today, to install swi-prolog with homebrew, simply do:

```
brew install swi-prolog
```

If you've installed it from the x11 bottle before, consider to uninstall an reinstall from the new location. Otherwise you might run into errors when updating/upgrading.

Comment: I used this command, It downloaded and I get the Welcome prompt but how do I create files?

Answer (score 5):

If you download the [SWI-Prolog application](http://www.swi-prolog.org/download/stable) into your `/Applications` folder, then add this to your `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="/Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/MacOS:$PATH"
```

The `swipl` binary lives in that MacOS directory. (Don't forget to `source ~/.bash_profile` after)

Answer (score 1):

There's now a handy [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/swipl/).